# How to convert assert method into checkThat() in junit?

Tags: junit

I am using assert statement to make test case fail, but I need to continue other assert statements even after first assert failure. To do that, I came to know Collector class is to be used. I now need to convert assert statement into checkThat() method. 
The below assert statement is to be converted into collector.checkThat() method.

Can anyone please help me?

```
assertTrue("Login failure",
                (SeleniumClass.waitUntilElementVisible(webDriver, By.xpath(".//*
[@id='xyz']"))));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Hamcrest CoreMatchers.

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;

collector.checkThat(
    "Login failure",
    SeleniumClass.waitUntilElementVisible(
        webDriver, By.xpath(".//*[@id='xyz']")
    ),
    is(true)
)
```